# Analysis of waveform after noise removal using Low pass FIR filter

Tags: matlab, filter, noise-reduction, lowpass-filter

I have a signal with fs = 200 Hz. Acc_X is my original waveform. I am applying A low pass FIR filter to remove noise.
The code is as :

```
order = 30;
wn = 25/100;
[b,a] = fir1(order,wn);
freqz(b,a)
x_f = filter(b,a,Acc_X);
close all;
subplot(2,1,1);plot(Acc_X);title('Unfiltered');
xlim([15000 16000])
subplot(2,1,2);plot(x_f);title('filtered');
xlim([15000 16000])
```

so clearly the order of the filter is 30 and cutoff frequency 25. After applying the filter, I plotted (a  part of)both the original and filtered waveform. The blue is the original one. I am not able to analyse this result, as I don't see any difference between both of them. How do I know the filter has removed noise? Also I selected the order of the filter randomly and if there is any better way to do it?

Any help over this will be helpful. Thanks in advance
[Please refer the image by clicking here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cewE.png)

Comment: Does the original signal contain any noise above the cutoff frequency? Try adding some white noise with  `Acc_X = Acc_X + rand(size(Acc_X));`

Comment: Thanks @LuisMendo. Its acceleration data collected via smartphone sensors, so I am assuming there is noise. When i used spectrogram over Acc_X, it showed me a lot of power was concentrated upto 25 Hz, thats why I used cutoff frequency as 25 Hz. My main objective was to remove the noise that might have been added while data collection

Comment: Well, you can see that the filter is actually removing some of the high-frequency components (i.e. fast variations) of the signal. See the marked regions [here](https://ibb.co/hRty5x7) (better zoom in to see it)